# understand design of php class to upload file

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm trying to refactor some messy code I've created and create classes that have a single responsibility. Struggled with this as tend to lump everything in a class and now it's difficult to maintain. My existing code works but messy.

I'm using the laravel 5.1 framework so a lot of the functionality already exists such is filesystem and I'm using an image manipulation package.

If I can get some help understanding a good approach to the following example I'm hoping I can then learn and continue refactoring the code.

So. I want the user to upload an image file to a server, create some thumbs then upload to a cloud storage.

The bit I'm struggling with is likely very basic - how to initiate the class.

I'm creating a new class that will upload the file: Here's the skeleton so far:

```
class FileUpload
{
private $originalFile;
private $validFiles = [
    'images' => ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'zip'],
    'documents' => ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'csv', 'pdf']
];
private $filepath;
private $filename;
private $validFileSize = [
    'image' => 10388608,
    'video' => 8388608,
    'other' => 4194304
];

public function _construct()
{

}


/**
 *  upload file to server
 * @param $file
 */
public function uploadFile($file)
{
    $this->setOriginalFile($file);
}

/**
 * check file size
 * check file size to ensure will be able to upload to server
 * 
 */
private function checkValidFileSize()
{
//        dostuff
}

/**
 * set file type attribute
 */
private function setFileType() {

}

/**
* set class attributes
**/
private function ($file) {
   // set attributes of class e.g.type, filename, filepath
}
```

}

In my controller I was going to do something on the lines of:

```
public function uploadFile(FileUpload $fileUpload) {

    $fileUpload->fileUpload($file);
}
```

I'm getting confused on the best way to initiate the creation of the `uploadFile` class - set the parameters and then do the actual upload.

I then want to take that file and manipulate it to create thumbs and resize etc if it's an image - which I'll do in another class

Then create a db entry for the file

Then finally upload to the a cloud storage

What is the best way to organise this code to ensure single responsibility and that it all joins together.

In the past I have made all the function calls from the controller - but this has become very lengthy and want to try and place the code in the right place.

Any help to point me in the right direction appreciated

Comment: You can simply put the class name on your controller variable as your example above, it will automatically resolved. Make sure that your variable of the `__construct()` method all are optional, if not then you must define it  on your `AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: I don't understand the part you say _I've created and create classes that have a single responsibility._ .. I count one class and it has many different responsibilities (logical if one class does it all). In other words, is this the class which was created out of messy code? Or is this class creating just as much mess as the code before?

Comment: Nope - this is not the original messy code but early thoughts on how I might organize (or new messy code depending on your point of view) this particular class to upload a file. So - as I say I'm trying to learn a better way so any constructive advice on how to best organise would be really helpful - how would you structure?